# Scanning an entire site for analytics tags

Tags: tags, analytics

We need to scan our entire site for certain analytic tags we fear might be missing.

Is there any tool out there that would allow us to do this in an automated fashion?  So we don't have to do the entire thing manually?

I looked into one tool here at  www.notagsnoglory.com but unfortunately they want to charge $1000 to scan for unique tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access to your site, you could just use the grep command to locate possible instances of the analytic tag:

```
> cd /path/to/your/site && grep -Rs "[string to search for]" * | grep -v "[anything you don't want to see]"
```

For example, if the tag you're looking for contains the string "google-analytics", and if you have output noise such as subversion tags, then your command might look something like this:

```
> grep -Rs "google-analytics" * | grep -v "svn"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob!  Unfortunately I don't have such access to my site.  It's built on CMS called TeamSite by Interwoven.  I believe the only thing that would work is some sort of spidering software.    Otherwise we could suck down the entire site and perhaps put it on a Linux system and do it your suggested way?

Comment: Yes, you could spider it.  If you're looking to go on the cheap for spidering, then from a local machine you could use wget -r http://yourweb.site/ .  It would show tags if they're visible to customers via client-side code.

Comment: How could I have wget only download pages if they LACK the analytics tags I want them to have?  Or how would that be possible?

Comment: hmm. If you use wget, you'd probably need to download all pages (hopefully not an impossible task), remove all the junk (like images and etc. where you know tags won't be), and then run a find on all file types you're looking for, removing all the ones that have the tags: # find ./ -name \*.html | grep -L [analytic-tag string] | xargs rm

Comment: Hi Rob - I'm a bit of a Linux newb.  So Running that Grep command will "remove" all of the pages that have the tags, leaving only the ones without the the tags?  Is it possible to do this in Windows at all?  Or OSX?

Comment: funny, I'm a bit of a Windows newb. :)  Correct, the "find" finds all files that end in 'html' (please feel free to change that of course based on need), and the grep -L finds filenames that contain the tag.  The 'xargs rm' removes the found files.  I'm sure there are equivalent Windows applications, but I don't know of them.  OSX has a command line that is similar to Linux and should have find, grep, and rm available.  You should be able to run that command after downloading the content to your OSX box.  You should also be able to install and run wget from the OSX box.